# How to remove Sessions from the database with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, session, laravel-5

I was trying to remove Session entries from the database's session table, which can be created using Laravel. Then I made a `UserController.php` containing nothing but the CRUD the-like functions.

Then I started the development webserver and it connected as expected to the database. When calling a Webpage (route) e.g. `http://localhost:8080/session/` the browser opened it and in the db there was an entry of a user (me) with IP ...1 in the `sessions` table.

Now I want to remove the session completely from the db by following the manually configured route `/remove`. The browser is guided correctly, opens the page and makes a request against the function to destroy the session.

Has anyone an explanation and a way to a solution? Do I have to implement my own Sessions Service or is there a way in Laravel to handle it? The documentation is quite short. It states how to create one but not how to delete it completely. [Laravel 5.2 - Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

There is no error or exception available.

Perhaps the record *was* removed, but Laravel creates a Session without asking so fast that I can't notice?

Perhaps I have an error in reasoning?

The mentioned `UserController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserController extends Controller{


    public function deleteSession(){
        $this->destroy(Session::getId());
        echo "Data has been perhaps removed from session table.";
    }


    public function index() {}
    public function create() {}
    public function store(Request $request) {}
    public function show($id) {}
    public function edit($id) {}
    public function update(Request $request, $id)   {}


    public function destroy($id)   {
        Session::forget($id);
        Session::flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: For Entirely remove session you have to use `Session::flush(); // removes all session data`. This link will help you: http://laravel.io/forum/02-06-2014-session-destroy

Comment: @Manish thx. But in the destroy function at the bottom I use this static call. It won't remove the record. I already tested it.

Comment: look at this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-store-users-id-in-session-table-laravel-5

Comment: @Manish yes I did, but it is not clear what you are pointing at. Is it to implement a service? Well, the Discussion on the external site points on storing a session, which laravel does automatically, as I found out myself. But it leaves the way to REMOVE a session still unanswered. I know I could write a hard delete by sending a direct SQL call, but I guess Laravel has another way. Or is it something the Laravel developers never thought of? I can't believe it would be true.

Comment: When you use forget it will forget a previously stored key not delete the session itself like Session::flash('some_key', 'some_value'); then  you can remove Session::forget('some_key'); btu the user will still be logged in